# How do I change and instance variable for an object which the user selects from a combobox?

Tags: java, swing, variables, combobox, instance

I'm a huge noob. I just finished a java textbook and now I'm making a game as a learning experiment. I'm stumped... here' my problem:

I have six objects created from the Person class.

Each object has a boolean variable, automatically set to false.

I can select each Person object from a combo-box and display information about them, but I can only display the information which I use to link the object to the combo box (as in:     person1.name    allows me to display the name variable on the combobox, and allows me to display the name elsewhere).

I want to be able to change other instance variables within each object. I know how to make a method to change each object, but I'd have to make six methods, one which specifically refers to each specific object.

I want to change the boolean instance variable for the object which the user selects from the combobox. I thought I could do this with an array of objects, but I've been failing to set up that array. Is an array the right way to go? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

- Your JComboBox appears to be holding String objects that correspond to each Person's name, i.e., `JComboBox<String>`.
- Instead, the JComboBox should hold a collection Person objects, `JComboBox<Person>`.
- You can control how the Person object is displayed by giving it a clean `toString()` method that returns the Person's name.
- Even better would be to give the JComboBox a custom cell renderer that properly display's the Person's name.
- Give the JComboBox an ActionListener to listen for the user's selection, get the selected object via the JComboBox's `getSelectedItem()`, and then call the appropriate setter method to set the selected Person's boolean field.

You state:

> I know how to make a method to change each object, but I'd have to make six methods, one which specifically refers to each specific object.

Not so. A single method would work just fine, one that can work with any number of Person objects.

If any of my suggestions are unclear, please let me know via a comment. If you've got more specific questions, please edit your original question, but also consider posting pertinent code as well.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PersonTest {
   protected static final Color SELECTED_COLOR = Color.red;

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Person[] people = { new Person("Duck", "Donald"),
            new Person("Mouse", "Mickey"), new Person("Trump", "Donald"),
            new Person("Bunny", "Easter"), new Person("Claus", "Santa"),
            new Person("Kringle", "Chris")};

      final JComboBox<Person> combo = new JComboBox<>(people);
      final JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(people);
      combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(combo));
      mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(personJList));

      combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Person selectedPerson = (Person) combo.getSelectedItem();
            selectedPerson.setCheck(!selectedPerson.isCheck());
            personJList.repaint();
         }
      });

      personJList.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
               Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Person person = (Person) value;
            Component component = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
                  value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (person != null) {
               if (person.isCheck()) {
                  component.setForeground(SELECTED_COLOR);
               } else {
                  component.setForeground(null);
               }
            }
            return component;
         }
      });

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PersonTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private boolean check;

   public Person(String lastName, String firstName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.check = false;
   }

   public boolean isCheck() {
      return check;
   }

   public void setCheck(boolean check) {
      this.check = check;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return String.format("%s,  %s", lastName, firstName);
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have to admit that your code is confusing to me. You do things differently than the textbook described. I'm going to painstakingly study this because it doesn't give warning when I paste it in NetBeans. Thanks for doing this. I'm sure I'll learn some good stuff.

Comment: @MattPayne: ask away if anything is confusing. For more on the details of creating a Swing GUI, please check out the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) as well as the complete [Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you `JComboBox` actually contains a reference to the `Person` object, you should provide suitable getters and setters which allow you access the value contain within the object.

For example...

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Creates a read only `Person`, the name can't be changed.

But, if we do...

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

This makes the name property writable as well, for example